# How to multiply specific rows/columns of matrices with each other in python?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, matrix-multiplication

I have to input matrices of shape

```
m1: (n,3)
m2: (n,3)
```

I want to multiply each row (each n of size 3) with its correspondence of the other matrix, such that i get a `(3,3)` matrix for each row.

When im trying to just use e.g. `m1[0]@m2.T[0]` the operation doesnt work, as `m[0]` delivers a `(3,)` list instead of a `(3,1)` matrix, on which i could use matrix operations.

Is there a relatively easy or elegant way to get the desired `(3,1)` matrix for the matrix multiplication?

Comment: I think you are trying to do an 'outer' product, producing a (n,3,3).  But I also see the use of `@` and 'matrix multiplication' suggesting an `inner` product.  Can you clean up the question?  Better yet, give a small example, eg. with (2,3) arrays, with desired result.  It will remove ambiguities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, numpy gets rid of the singleton dimension, as you have noticed.
You can use `np.newaxis` (or equivalently `None`. That is an implementation detail, but also works in pytorch) for the second axis to tell numpy to "invent" a new one.

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.ones((3,3))
a[1].shape                 # this is (3,)
a[1,:].shape               # this is (3,)
a[1][...,np.newaxis].shape # this is (3,1)
```

**However**, you can also use `dot` or `outer` directly:

```
>>> a = np.eye(3)
>>> np.outer(a[1], a[1])
array([[0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.]])
>>> np.dot(a[1], a[1])
1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally, I would recommend using `np.einsum` for most matrix operations as it very elegant.
To obtain a the row-wise outer product of the vectors contained in `m1` and `m2` of shape `(n, 3)` you could do the following:

```py
import numpy as np
m1 = np.array([1, 2, 3]).reshape(1, 3)
m2 = np.array([1, 2, 3]).reshape(1, 3)
result = np.einsum("ni, nj -> nij", m1, m2)
print(result)
>>>array([[[1, 2, 3],
        [2, 4, 6],
        [3, 6, 9]]])
```